# How to define a type in my GraphQL for list of Objects in an object

Tags: graphql

I'm quite new to graphql and don't know how do I define a type for my Objects list in an object, I can find tutorials on internet about object list in an array, not in an object. I'm attaching my data, in this I've tried to write an object type in the Schema, but it doesn't seem to working, please any help would be more than appreciated, Thanks in Advance!

```
    var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const {buildSchema} = require('graphql');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: buildSchema(`

    type topicInfo{
      id: String!
      topicName: String!
      topicDescription: String!
      topicTags: [String!]!
    }

    type RootQuery {
      topicCards: topicInfo
    }
    type RootMutation {
      createEvent(name:String) : String
    }
    schema {
      query: RootQuery
      mutation: RootMutation
    }
  `),
  rootValue: {
    topicCards: () =>{
      return (
        {
          "topic-1": {
            id: "topic-1",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 1",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-2": {
            id: "topic-2",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 2",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-3": {
            id: "topic-3",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 3",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-4": {
            id: "topic-4",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 4",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-5": {
            id: "topic-5",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 5",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-6": {
            id: "topic-6",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 6",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-7": {
            id: "topic-7",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 7",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-8": {
            id: "topic-8",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 8",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-9": {
            id: "topic-9",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 9",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          "topic-10": {
            id: "topic-10",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 10",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
        }
      )
    }
  },
  graphiql:true
}));

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly changed your code and this should work. The changes are, 1: the topicCards function need to respond an array and not a dict. 2. In the resolver, you need to do the same.

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: buildSchema(`

    type topicInfo{
      id: String!
      topicName: String!
      topicDescription: String!
      topicTags: [String!]!
    }

    type RootQuery {
      topicCards: [topicInfo]
      topicCardById (id: String!): topicInfo
    }

    type RootMutation {
      createEvent(name:String) : String
    }
    schema {
      query: RootQuery
      mutation: RootMutation
    }
  `),
  rootValue: {
    topicCardById: (obj, args, context, info) => {
      return ({
         id: "topic-1",
         topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 1",
         topicDescription: "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
         topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
      });
    }
    topicCards: () =>{
      return (
        [
          {
            id: "topic-1",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 1",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          {
            id: "topic-2",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 2",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          },
          {
            id: "topic-3",
            topicName: "Adding a feature: GSoC 3",
            topicDescription:
              "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.",
            topicTags: ["ReactJs", "NodeJS"],
          }
        ]
      )
    }
  },
  graphiql:true
}));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll try this, this should work, what if my client side is depending on dict based data, should I implement that changing on the client side only?
Basically what I'm doing is mapping data based on dict property like "topic-1" and all so I'll be needing that in my data.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand. If in the client side, you are looking for id based object, then you have to convert there. However, for that you can use separate api to get one object based on id.

Comment: Okay, but the problem is still not clear, even for one object in my dictionary let's say topic-1, how do I send it, like I'm pretty beginner in my GraphQL knowledge please help me :(

Comment: I've updated my answer with another function which fetches single object based on id as parameter. Hope this helps